# crop in add_image_size() wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

Why does crop array in add_image_size() does not work properly unless the featured image is again uploaded?
Like here is the code
    `<?php add_image_size('banner-image', 920, 210, array('center','center')); ?>`

This works perfectly for the first time but when I change the above code to
    `<?php add_image_size('banner-image', 920, 210, array('left','top')); ?>`

It does not work on normal or hard refresh but image is cropped to left top when the featured image is again uploaded.

Any solution for this without cropping the image when uploading...

Comment: did you try with regenerate thumbnail plugin?

Comment: I want to work on this without using any plugin.

Comment: after upload the image not croped again. you should use to regenerate with new size regenerate thumbnail plugin

Comment: Hopefully, this helps. Thanks.